# Does sorting by IS NULL use an index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

Does the following query (specifically the ORDER BY price IS NULL DESC) use the index on the price column?

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price IS NULL DESC, price DESC

product_id | price
-----------|------
1           5
2           6
3           NULL
4           8
```

I would like the query to return

```
product_id | price
-----------|------
3           NULL
4           8
2           6
1           5
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see what indexes are used.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is causing the query to use filesort.... wanted verification of my findings

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: I would not expect changing `ORDER BY price DESC` to `ORDER BY price IS NULL DESC, price DESC` would change whether indexes are used.  "Using filesort" does not mean no index is used.  Add EXPLAIN of both queries to your question if you want informed answers

Answer (score 0):

You are not purely "sorting by `IS NULL`"; you have a composite (multi-column) index.

That `ORDER BY` is too complex to avoid a "sort".  (Note:  'filesort' does not necessarily involve a 'file', this example is likely to do all the work in RAM.)

The processing goes something like this:

- Collect 3 columns:  product_id, price, (price IS NULL)
- Note that `price IS NULL` had to be evaluated, getting 0 (not null) or 1 (is null)
- Logically combine the 0/1 with the price to make a 2-column pair of columns to drive the sorting
- Sort
- Deliver the results.

If you had said simply `ORDER BY price DESC`, `INDEX(price)` *could* be used, but it would sort the `NULLs` last.  (I say "could" because the "filesort" might be faster than bouncing between the index's BTree and the data.)

Caveat:  You have probably "simplified" the query for the Question.  In response, I have addressed your simplified query.  And I provided some hints that may Answer may or may not apply in the "general case".